# Buttons and sounds?

Tags: android, button, audio

i have try to make mediaplayer, and my problem is how to set sound stop when you click next sound button. Now if i click sound button it works but if i click a new sound, it works too but that first one not stop.

here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void onClick(View v){}
    public void btn1 (View v){
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.est1);
    mp.start();
    }
    public void btn2 (View v){
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ast2);
    mp.start();
    }
    public void btn3 (View v){
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dst3);
    mp.start();
    }
    public void btn4 (View v){
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gstd4);
    mp.start();
    }
    public void btn5 (View v){
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bstd5);
    mp.start();
    }
    public void btn6 (View v){
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.estd6);
    mp.start();


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use only one MediaPlayer that you can reset and reuse.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
    }

    public void btn1 (View v){
        mp.release();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.est1);
        mp.start();
    }
    public void btn2 (View v){
        mp.release();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.est1);
        mp.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
       mp.release();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have 6 different MediaPlayers. 
You have to pause all media players and then start the current one.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried mp.stop();

This should stop the first sound

```
 public void btn5 (View v){
    mp.stop();
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bstd5);
    mp.start();
    }
```

like here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html